# Flask app. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am trying to create my first Flask app where I am getting user data, doing a vlookup(merge) to add a few columns to the user, then doing a prediction on the whole dataframe. The problem is I cannot read my CSV data saved in the static folder so as to do the merge. Flask cannot see the csv files. Any help will be highly appreciated:
Here is my code snippet

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

def predict():
  if request.method == 'POST':

with open("static/region_map.csv", "r") as f1:
        region_map = f1.read()
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/region_map.csv'

Comment: Are you sur of your path ? Did you tried with the full path ?

Comment: Hi. region_map.csv is in a folder called static at the same directory where the app.py is located.

Answer (score 0):

The values for paths set during configuration can be requested. These are absolute and should work. The static directory can be queried using the [`static_folder`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.static_folder) attribute.

```
import os

def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        target = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'region_map.csv')
        with open(target) as fp:
            region_map = fp.read()
    # ...
```

The [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function opens the file and returns a file object. If you read the content in text mode using [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), you will in fact get a string back.
To get a dataframe from a csv file, it is advisable to use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=csv#pandas-read-csv).

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def predict():
    target = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'region_map.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(target)
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Any idea how I can turn the data into a dataframe after reading it? Seems like it comes out as a string

Comment: @ElijahKalii Updated my answer.